# QInputDialog.getItem() get item index

Tags: c++, qt, dialog

I have some list and `QInputDialog`. There may be same strings in my list, so i want to get not the string result but item index. Is it real?

```
QStringList list;
for (Serial serial: serialList->vector) {
    list.append(serial.name);
}

QInputDialog *dialog = new QInputDialog();
bool accepted;
QString item = dialog->getItem(0, "Title", "Label:", list, 0, false, &accepted);
if (accepted && !item.isEmpty()) {
    qDebug() << dialog->?????; //here i want to see index of choosen item
}
```

I've tried to use `result()` but it is not working. Help, please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `QInputDialog` has no such method. But of course this information has combobox inside dialog.

### **Can you access this combobox?**

I think that it is not good idea. Look at the [source code](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt-maemo/source/f88f86b2bebe841631bd34ca5611495de03b6a95:src/gui/dialogs/qinputdialog.cpp#L762) of `QInputDialog`:

```
void QInputDialog::setComboBoxItems(const QStringList &items)
{
    Q_D(QInputDialog);
    d->ensureComboBox();
    d->comboBox->blockSignals(true);
    d->comboBox->clear();
    d->comboBox->addItems(items);
    d->comboBox->blockSignals(false);
    if (inputMode() == TextInput)
        d->chooseRightTextInputWidget();
}
```

As you can see your combobox is hidden by `d-pointer` and it is normal practice in `Qt`(hide implementation details). [More information here.](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Dpointer)

### **Probably the best solution:**

Use [`indexOf()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstringlist.html#lastIndexOf-2) method from `QStringList`. For example:

```
int index = list.indexOf(item);
```

Comment: Thanks. This solution came to my mind first, but as i said strings could be same, so i can't solve my problem in that way.

Comment: @Efog Hm, it is really problem, are you sure that same strings is necessary here, how user should know about difference between these items, can you for example use Same,Same(1),Same(2) just to avoid absolutely same strings?

Comment: There are list of films which could be added by link. So, if user add 2 same films he will want to delete second one. (1) (2) is good idea. I "solved" my problem in another way: in my list i'm adding "1. ", "2. " before film names and then `int index = item.split('.')[0].toInt() - 1` :D Of course, your solution is better. Thanks!

Comment: @Efog It is very good, because without this we need to create our own dialog with combobox(because playing with d-pointer can be really very hard and long). QInputDialog just very general class, we use it for int, text, comboxes and so on and of course we can't get full control in this case, so it is very good that specification of your task allows you to avoid creating custom dialog with combobox.

Answer (score 0):

```
QStringList list;
for (Serial serial: serialList->vector) {
    list.append(serial.name);
}

QInputDialog *dialog = new QInputDialog();
bool accepted;
QString item = dialog->getItem(0, "Title", "Label:", list, 0, false, &accepted);
if (accepted && !item.isEmpty()) {
    int ind=-1;
    for (int i =0;i<dialog->children().count();i++)
    {
        qDebug()<<dialog->children().at(i);
        QComboBox *combox = qobject_cast<QComboBox*>(dialog->children().at(i));
        if (combox)
        {
            ind = combox->currentIndex(); // index of select
        }

    }
}
```

You can try it.
Is work for me.